# Angular HTTP Interceptor Testing - Changing the window.location.href value

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8

I have following code in my HTTP interceptor

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {

          if (error.status === 401 && location.href.indexOf('localhost') === -1) {
              localStorage.setItem('some key', 'some data');
          }

          return throwError(error);
        }
      ));
  }
```

As you can see, if I get a 401 status and `href` doesn't contain `localhost`, I am persisting the some data to `localStorage`.

When I am writing the Unit Test cases for this piece of code, the question came, how do I change the `href` value so that I can verify correct data is getting persisted?

I know there are some workarounds (using `Angular location` or by writing a wrapper to get `location` object.

But my question is, whether or how can I mock or change the global location object directly in my test cases?

Comment: You would have to mock your environment to fake the `location` object.

Comment: This is hard because you're coupled to the `location` object. Maybe write a facade and inject that, so you can use a test double in the tests? Same with `localStorage`.

Comment: Why not instead use/inject [Angular Location](https://angular.io/api/common/Location) which you can then easily mock/spy/stub?

Answer (score 0):

it is not good o use location or localStorage or any global object directly inside the class. it is better to inject them in constructor so you can mock them when writing unit tests.

First provide location with providers in your core.module. if there is no core.module provide it at app.module or main.ts file.

```
providers: [
  { provide: "location", useValue: location }
],
```

then you can inject location at the class constructor

```
constructor(
   @Inject("location") private location: Location
) {}
```

then use the injected location

```
if (error.status === 401 && this.location.href.indexOf('localhost') === -1) {
   localStorage.setItem('some key', 'some data');
}
```

Now you can easily mock location object in your spec file and change the location.href for each test case.

if you don't want to use string "location" as injector token to avoid spelling mistakes you can provide location using InjectionToken instead.

```
import {InjectionToken} from '@angular/core';
export location = new InjectionToken('location');
```

its better to separate this in new file so you can import the location token to provide at app.module and inject at your interceptor

```
providers: [
  { provide: location, useValue: location }
],
```